# Backbone.js model or collection?

Tags: backbone.js

Im quite new to backbone and thinking of collections vs model. Lets say i have to do a json-call to an endpoint wich only returns 2-3 properties in one single object. Is it then really necessary to use a collection for that one single model?

Or can i just do the call directly from a model and then use it in my view. I mean, does the model have the same functionallity as a collection? i.e you can load, fetch, parse etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can populate model from a server with a [model.fetch](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-fetch) call. To do this you'll have to set [url](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-url) for your model.

Answer (score 0):

In Backbone, `Models` represent *entities* for your application domain while `Collections` are a way to group models by type.

`Collections` are basically helpers when dealing with multiple instances of a given `Model`. They've got functions to sort, filter or iterate (and some more from `Underscore.js`) and also have several functions to deal with `Model` creation such as `fetch`, `create`, etc.

Since they're helping you deal with multiple models, `Collections` have an [`url` attribute](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-url) which is used by its models to build `urls` when communicating with server individually.

So, if you just have info for an *entity* you will use a `Model` (i.e: `http://host.com/entity/3`). If you have an URL for several *entities*, you may use a `Collection` (i.e: `http://host.com/entities`). However, keep in mind that you may use `Collections` just for grouping and easier use, even when you don't have any URL for it.